# Is Apple Video Encoder (hevc) Lossless?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, h.264, video-encoding, hevc

I want to know if Apple Video Encoder for iOS supports lossless compression or not with hevc (h265) codec? If yes, what are the compression settings for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HEVC itself is a lossless codec [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding). So yes, Apple's VideoToolBox supported HEVC compression is also lossless.

By lossless, it means that whatever data it can capture (8 bit/ 10 bit), if it compresses them using HEVC, it can decompress back to what it originally captured.

Now regarding compression settings to achieve lossless, first I need to know are you going to use Apple's VideoToolbox library to configure the compressor ? Or something else ?

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out the settings for VideoToolbox to do lossless HEVC? I tried setting quality to 1.0, but it doesn't seem to be lossless.

Answer (score 2):

While certain implementations [have a lossless option](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lossless.html), HEVC is a mathematically lossy codec by default. The docs don't mention if the iOS libraries support that option, so we can't safely assume it's available unless proven otherwise.

Lossless h264 takes a relatively good chunk of computing power and space to work, so likely isn't ideal for a default mobile option.

When it comes to intermediaries and folks chasing quality, visually 'lossless' won't cut it. Unless it can be converted back bit-for-bit, generational loss will occur.

TL;DR: ¯\*(ツ)*/¯